# Lararel Mix compiling css blank page

Tags: laravel, webpack

I'm trying to compile a css file with Laravel-mix but for some reason when i try to include the file in the header the page is blank with no errors.

webpack.mix.js

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
require('vuetifyjs-mix-extension')
require('laravel-mix-purgecss');
const cssImport = require('postcss-import')
const cssNesting = require('postcss-nesting')


mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vuetify('vuetify-loader').vue()
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css').purgeCss()
   .postCss('../assets/css/custom.css', 'public/css', [
      cssImport(),
      cssNesting(),
      require('tailwindcss'),
   ]).purgeCss()
```

importing it in the header

```
<link href="{{ mix('css/custom.css', 'core/public') }}" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

the file gets included in the header correctly also i can look at the file and it's contents, also CSS is applied as far as i can tell looking at the body.

**Edit
Most CSS doesn't get compiled and it's missing from the file which gets generated from webpack

package.json

```
    "laravel-mix": "^6.0.27",
    "laravel-mix-purgecss": "^6.0.0",
```

Laravel Version 5.8

**Edit
I found out why the page is blank, it's a Vuetify issue where v-app is covering the page, i had set this CSS property inside the file which fixed this issue

```
div > .v-application--wrap {
    min-height: auto !important;
  }
```

The problem is this CSS property is missing in the compiled webpack file.